# Breaking in functions passed to LINQ-functions

Tags: c#, visual-studio-debugging, first-class-functions

I have a function that is passed to `Select`. But when I put a breakpoint in said function the program does not break.

Example:

```
public static int PlusTwo(int x)
{
  return x + 2;
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
  var foo = new[] { 2, 3, 5, 7 };
  var bar = foo.Select(PlusTwo);
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's because of the lazy evaluation. If you try doing a `ToList()`, the function would evaluate and the break-point would be hit - i.e. try doing:

```
var bar = foo.Select(PlusTwo).ToList();
```

Answer (score 6):

Enumerables are lazy evaluated.

This means that your function will not be called until you start to iterate over the result.

If you add:

```
for(var x in bar) ...
```

Then your function will be called.

If you want to get result immediately, call `bar.ToArray()` or `bar.ToList()`. This will internally iterate through the enumerable to create the result, which will ensure that the function is called.

Answer (score 1):

You are using LINQ which has deferred execution. In other words it will not execute until you want the result of that operation. So if you had to do a foreach over it; it would then execute.